# Unable to Build React Native Project Due to Bintray Closure and Missing Firebase Library

Tags: spring, firebase, react-native, maven, gradle

I'm encountering an issue while trying to build my React Native project, particularly related to the Firebase library, since the closure of Bintray. I'm getting the following error message:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'jagain'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-plugins/1.1.1/firebase-plugins-1.1.1.pom
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-plugins/1.1.1/firebase-plugins-1.1.1.jar
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-plugins/1.1.1/firebase-plugins-1.1.1.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-plugins/1.1.1/firebase-plugins-1.1.1.jar
       - https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/google/firebase/firebase-plugins/1.1.1/firebase-plugins-1.1.1.pom
       - https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/google/firebase/firebase-plugins/1.1.1/firebase-plugins-1.1.1.jar
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-plugins/1.1.1/firebase-plugins-1.1.1.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-plugins/1.1.1/firebase-plugins-1.1.1.jar
```

I've trade to use repo.spring.io, but the response is 401

This is the build.gradle file.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
 
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
        // maven {
        //     url "https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/"
        // }
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0")
        classpath('com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0')
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.1'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        // ADD THIS
        // maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }

        // ADD THIS
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        // maven {
        //     url "https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release"
        // }
        mavenCentral()

        // Add the midtrans repository into the list of repositories
        // maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/pt-midtrans/maven" }
    }
}
```